# Pre-Select an Item based on GET

Tags: php, html

I to pre select an Item in a Listbox based on the value from `$_GET`.

Ex: Selectbox with options 1,2,3. from the url I get the value 2. How do I preselect this value? The way with `<option ...selected>...</>` is way too complicated. I just want to declare which option is pre-selected, like `<select selected="2">`.

Comment: Could you show us how the listbox is being outputted? Is it outputted by PHP?

Answer (score 3):

**The solution with the less number of `if` statements in my answer is the last one.**

Unfortunately, there's no way to so `<select selected="2">`. You'll have to do something like this:

```
<select name="select">
  <option value="1"<?php if ( $_GET['select'] == '1' ): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>Option 1</option>
  <option value="2"<?php if ( $_GET['select'] == '2' ): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>Option 2</option>
  <option value="3"<?php if ( $_GET['select'] == '3' ): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

If you allow mutliples, I would use `in_array` and make sure that the `select` element's name specifies that it's an array (using the square brackets).

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="multi_select[]">
  <option value="1"<?php if ( in_array('1', $_GET['multi_select']) ): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>Option 1</option>
  <option value="2"<?php if ( in_array('2', $_GET['multi_select']) ): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>Option 2</option>
  <option value="3"<?php if ( in_array('3', $_GET['multi_select']) ): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

As an alternative, you could use a PHP `array` to create the options and a `foreach` loop to create the `option`.

```
<select name="select">
<?php

$options = array(
  1 => 'Option 1',
  2 => 'Option 2',
  3 => 'Option 3'
);

foreach ( $options as $value => $name )
{
  echo '<option value="' . $value . '"' . ( $_GET['select'] == $value ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ) . '>' . $name . '</option>';
}

?>
</select>
```

Comment: @Michael Mior - My last option doesn't have as many `if` statements. But with that said, if the plan is to use regular HTML, how else would you suggest doing it so that it works with clients that have JavaScript disabled? I'm all for jQuery but some people still disable JavaScript and I think that a all-HTML option is much better suited for something so simple.

Comment: I didn't suggest that Javascript was a good idea. I don't think it is. I also somehow missed your last option in the answer. Looks much prettier :)

Comment: @Michael Mior - No worries. I agree that the last option looks prettier. It's the one I would choose. I just wanted to give the OP as many options as possible that don't require JavaScript.

Comment: Totally. JS is nice and all, but it's often relied on far too heavily. PS - I can't remove the downvote I added unless you edit your answer. Sorry about that...

Comment: @yes123 - Ternary isn't an `if`, technically. It's a conditional statement that resolves to one of 2 expressions unlike the `if` statement that's branches the flow and cannot be assigned to a variable.

Comment: Joking :d... I said that beacuse there is a way to do this without any if/ternary. But ur solut is good enough

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to have a selected tag indicate which one is selected. It has to be done through the option tag.

Have you thought about looping through the options?

```
$desiredSelect = $_GET['desired'];

foreach( array('option-value'  => 'option-text',
               'option-value2' =>'option-text2' ) as $val => $test )
{
    echo "<option value=\"$val\" ";
    if( $val == $desiredSelect ) echo "selected = \"selected\"";
    echo ">$text</option>";
}
```

Comment: +! for not having an if statement for each option.

Answer (score 1):

An options could be to inject a simple JavaScript/jQuery script to be fired on DOM ready if the request was a get:

if request is get, then inject this code into the response HTML:

```
$(function(){
    $('#selectBox').val(selectedItemValue);
});
```

It's that simple. :)

Comment: If you don't care about people without Javascript and if you're using jQuery. And if `selectedItemValue` is magically set.

Comment: selectedItemValue could be created at server (inline PHP), and if you want to set the selected value of the select box at server, then it's already being set beforehand by the client, so you know it. But you're right. It needs a little JavaScript/jQuery familiarity :)

Comment: My point was that it's not quite that simple since you left out code that is required for this to work and which might be non-obvious to someone not familiar with Javascript. Solution would definitely work though :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you have two ways: the first one is to compare each element to selected (as did @Francois Deschenes and @cwallenpoole); the second one is workaround and because of that not very good, but easier to implement. You can use javascript to set selected item to needed after list is formed:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('select[selected]').val(function() {
        return $(this).attr('selected')
    })
});
</script>
<select selected="7">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <!-- ... -->
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Oh, @Saeed Neamati posted smth same while I was writing :)

Answer (score 0):

Another non-if non-js version could possibly be something like this

```
<?
$res = array($_GET["selected"] => " selected='selected'");    
?>


<select name="select">
  <option value="1"<? echo $res['1']; ?>>Option 1</option>
  <option value="2"<? echo $res['2']; ?>>Option 2</option>
  <option value="3"<? echo $res['3']; ?>>Option 3</option>
</select>
```